# Issue with environment variable

Tags: batch-file, environment

I just want to echo a variable which is defined with ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION. It doesn't work.
Here's a small part of my long script on the issue

```
  @echo off&setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 for /f "tokens=*" %%x in (%1) do (
  set "D=%%x"
  echo %%~nD
 )
```

I have also written   echo !~nD! but it doesn't work either.

my file (%1) only contains relative paths as so:

```
VENDOR\ford1.car
VENDOR\bmw.car
```

and my goal is to echoing 'ford1.car' or 'bmw.car' because I have to use them in the next steps of my script, that is only the file complete name.

Please some help and explanations. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
@echo off&setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%1) do (
   echo %%~nxa
 )
```

For only does substitution on the variable used in the for. You can't set a variable within and use substitution on it.

%%~na would only give you the file name without the extension. You have to use %%~nxa to get the file name and the extension.

If you want to set the file name to a variable and do something with each file, you have to use DelayedExpansion like this:

```
@echo off&setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%1) do (
   set d=%%~nxa
   echo !d!
   Do something with !d!
 )
```

Or you could create a subroutine and not have to use a variable at all

```
@echo off&setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%1) do (
   call :sub %%~nxa
 )
 goto :eof

:sub
%1 = your file name so do some processing on it.
```

Comment: Indeed, I want to use %%~nxa out of the for command in the same batch script . It's why I set the variable 'D' and use enabledelayedexpansion in order to expand it and use that later. Thanks

Comment: You don't need to use DelayedExpansion unless this for is nested within another for loop or you want to set a variable inside the for and reference it inside the for loop.